# Open image from drawable into gallery intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, android-image, android-drawable

I would like to open just one image and have pitch-zoom function, so (as I think) easiest way to do that is to open that image in gallery intent. Anybody can share example of how to call gallery intent with particular picture from drawable?

I tried to used something like that but can't make it working (wrong file patch?).

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("com.me.example/drawable/thisimage.png"), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://androidbook.blogspot.in/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html)

You should do something like:

```
 String uriStr = "android.resource://"+ "com.example.myapp"+ "/" +  R.drawable.photo_h01;
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriStr);
```

I have not Eclipse in front of me but that's what I have found on several sources

Comment: That gives an error - no activity found to handle intent. The patch for image is most likely correct but I don't know how to call gallery intent. CODE: Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String uriStr = "android.resource://"+ "com.example.myapp(suited to my app)"+ "/" +  R.drawable.map;Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriStr);intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);